# Fail on recognising entry point: Can not resolve 'file' or 'directory' './src/index.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

First of all, i know we should post complete and reproducible questions.
However, i am doing a full stack Redux tutorial (http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html),
and i close to the end, which means i have a lot of files and logic already implemented.
For this reason, I loaded my project to github, which is publicly available (https://github.com/rafaelmarques7/voting_app_tutorial). This way, it is simple to see the project structure and files, and even to clone the project and reproduce the error.

So here is the question
when i run npm run dev, i get the following errors:

```
ERROR in multi main Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./src/index.js in C:\Users\Y\Desktop\sketches\voting_app\client_side
  @ multi main
```

and relating to webpack

```
ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'sockjs-client' in
  C:\Users\Y\Desktop\sketches\voting_app\client_side\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client
  @ (webpack)-dev-server

ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client?  Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'
  C:\Users\Y\Desktop\sketches\voting_app\client_side\node_modules\url\url.js in
  C:\Users\Y\Desktop\sketches\voting_app\client_side\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client
  @ (webpack)-dev-server/client? 1:10-24
```

I actually tried extensively to solve this error, searching both stackoverflow, and github related issues, but none of the solutions presented was capable of  solving my error.

Any suggestion?
I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your `resolve` configuration.

```
resolve: {
  modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  packageMains: ['webpack']
},
```

The first one is that [`resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions) requires an empty string to be able to import files with the full extension. For example if you import `./index.js` it will try to resolve it with the configured extensions (`./index.js.js` and `./index.js.jsx` in your case). **This is a webpack 1 issue** and the current `resolve.extensions` would work fine in webpack 2 or higher (in fact, an empty string is not allowed any more).

The second issue is `resolve.packageMains`. This option is used when you import a node module (a directory with a `package.json`). Webpack will look for these fields in the `package.json` and uses the specified file as the entry point of the module. Node uses the `main` field to determine the entry point, hence npm packages all have a `main` field. You're only looking for a `webpack` field, which barely any package has. A newer field that is much more widely used is `module` (see [Rollup - pkg.module](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg.module) for details). You should use the default of [`resolve.mainFields`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfields) from webpack 2+ (the option has been renamed).

Your `resolve` config becomes:

```
resolve: {
  modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  packageMains: ['browser', 'module', 'main']
},
```

The tutorial is almost 2 years old and therefore uses some old versions. It is highly recommended to upgrade webpack, because it has improved immensely. As you're dealing with a new project with a simple config, it won't take much effort to upgrade with the [official migration guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/).

Comment: it finnaly compiled!
you saved my life, thank you very much!